# Redux React state not getting set after data received from reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-reducers

i do have a component in which

```
state={
mediaJson=[]
}
```

and i have a reducer which calls an API and returns data and i used

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
return{
mediaJson:props.data
}
```

i am getting the data and ist getting displayed

as per my understanding its kind of setting to the state named mediaJson ,again in another click function

```
tabClicks = (val) => {
const mediaContent = [...this.state.mediaJson];
}
```

and tried to console  mediaContent this am getting undefined

Comment: First off, reducer is [supposed](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers/#handling-actions) to stay pure function (which means, it shouldn't do any side-effects, like fetching API data); Next, you're [misusing](https://uk.reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#when-to-use-derived-state) `getDerivedStateFromProps`. Your proper choice would be to use `connect()` and [`mapStateToProps`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate#defining-mapstatetoprops) to bind your component to certain part of global state or use hook alternatives.

Comment: If you wish, you may post wider code context and broader explanation of what you're trying to achieve and I may suggest conventional approach to solve your problem with React/Redux.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov didnt get exactly ,cant it be used for API calls ? it shouldnt do any side effects means ?

Comment: If you need to do API calls, you may employ action creators for that purpose, possibly, together with some middleware (like redux-thunk). As being said, state your problem clearly, append your code to see approach you're following them you may get relevant answer.